# HDMI output on Windows 7 PC does not stay alive

Tags: windows-7, video, hdmi

I have built a server that is connected only to my TV via HDMI.

If I switch my TV's input to HDMI and boot my server I get the expected result (Windows is displayed on my TV) and I can fully interact with it, no problem.

However when "some time" passes the image on my TV disappears and it seems the server is not outputting any HDMI signal anymore. It does not wake up on keyboard presses or mouse movement.

I can still interact with my server through a remote desktop session.

The only way to get the HDMI output back is to reboot the server.

I tried to prevent the computer from "sleeping" but this did not work. I also tried upgrading from Windows Vista to Windows 7 but this also did not work.

Any ideas and/or solutions to this problem?

Comment: Have you checked for a bios update?